# Help me install guest additions on Ubuntu 11.04

Tags: 11.04, 10.04, virtualbox, windows-xp

I'm having problems installing guest additions on a Ubuntu 11.04 guest os.  The host os is Windows XP pro

On the host os (Windows XP), I also have another guest os Ubuntu 10.04, and I have had no problem installing guest additions on that.

When I try installing guest additions on the guest os Ubuntu 11.04, I get a message saying

> The headers for the current running
>   kernel was not found

So I installed

> linux-headers-generic

Tried installing guest additions again, and got the same message as before:

> The headers for the current running
>   kernel was not found

So my question is, how do I install guest additions on the guest os ubuntu 11.04 where Windows XP is the host os. I just checked with `uname -a` to get the correct version, then check using aptitude and noticed that the correct version is already installed.

I am using VirtualBox 4.0.8.

Comment: Have you seen [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/22743/how-do-i-install-guest-additions-in-virtual-box)? It's the same for 11.04 where you start in Gnome classic anyway.

Comment: Do you have a PAE kernel? What is the output of `uname -r`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to install the kernel modules (headers) package that match the kernel version you are running the Ubuntu virtual machine with.

Type the following command in the terminal:

```
uname -a
```

This will give you line like this:

```
Linux dirk-Studio-1558 2.6.38-9-generic #43-Ubuntu SMP Thu Apr 28 15:23:06 UTC 2011 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

The first word is the type of system, the second is the name of your machine and the third one is the one you are looking for. It gives the kernel version.

So you need to install the linux-headers-{my kernel version here} package from Synaptic org using apt-get. In my case it would be

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-2.6.38-9-generic
```

or directly in one generic command:

```
sudo apt-cache search linux-headers-`uname -r`
```

Hope that helps!

**edit:**

Ok, if that is setup correctly you can try to install the packages listed [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/virtualbox-guest-additions/+bug/738330)
Check post #12

Comment: I just checked with `uname -a` to get the correct version, then check using `aptitude` and noticed that the correct version is already installed.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and found that I need the `linux-kernel-devel` package.
Since `apt-get` could not find it, i used `apt-file search` and found `linux-kernel` inside the `virtualbox-ose-guest-dkms package`.

So
`sudo apt-get install virtualbox-ose-guest-dkms`

solved the problem with the warning.